# xpath - element containing exact text, but minus sibling elements?

Tags: xpath

Without using index specificity. I'm trying to target an element with exact text, but which also ignores the text of sibling elements. For example, target the span with Save below.

```
<span>Click and save money!</span>

<span>
  <i>Icon</i> 
  Save
</span>
```

So something like //span[contains(text(), 'Save')] would grab any span with "Save" in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the xpath : `//span[text()[normalize-space(.)='Save']]`

It looks for `span` elements which have text nodes whose space-trimmed value is exactly `Save`